# Mapping a .jsp to a Controller in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, heroku

I am just starting with spring so I started with a SpringMVC on Heroku. By choosing the Spring MVC Template in Eclipse I got a very basic Application. Now I am trying to modify this.

However if I create another `.jsp` and I visit the URL given in the Controller I get an 404, that's pretty clear, because I never mapped the Controller to the `.jsp`. But how should I do this?

Here is everything I changed (Even if I'm not sure that you will need it):

The Controller:

```
@Controller
public class BookingController {

    @Autowired
    BookingService bookingService;

    @RequestMapping("/AvailableBikes")
    public String getAvailableBikes(Model model){
        // TOOD: Fix Date
        int availableBookings = bookingService.getAvailableBookings(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        model.addAttribute("NumAvailableBikes", Integer.toString(availableBookings));

        return "NumAvailableBikes";
    }

}
```

The Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Booking {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;


// Lots of getters setters an attributes ...

}
```

The Service:

```
@Service
public class BookingServiceImpl implements BookingService {

    @Override
    public void addBooking(Booking booking) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public int getAvailableBookings(Date bookingDay) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 12;
    }

    @Override
    public void removeBooking(Booking booking) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

booking.jsp:

```
<!doctype html>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Spring MVC and Hibernate Template</title>

    <meta content="IE=edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

Test!

<h2>${NumAvailableBikes}</h2>

</body>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>Spring-Hibernate-Template</display-name>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/booking/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.stuttgart.fahrrad" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>

    </bean>

    <beans profile="default">
        <jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource"/>        
        <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
            <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
                <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
            </property>
            <property name="jpaProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </beans>

    <beans profile="prod">
        <bean class="java.net.URI" id="dbUrl">
            <constructor-arg value="#{systemEnvironment['DATABASE_URL']}"/>
        </bean>

        <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
            <property name="url" value="#{ 'jdbc:postgresql://' + @dbUrl.getHost() + @dbUrl.getPath() }"/>
            <property name="username" value="#{ @dbUrl.getUserInfo().split(':')[0] }"/>
            <property name="password" value="#{ @dbUrl.getUserInfo().split(':')[1] }"/>
        </bean>

        <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
            <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
                <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
            </property>
            <property name="jpaProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                    <!-- change this to 'verify' before running as a production app -->
                    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </beans>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

return "NumAvailableBikes"; should be changed to return "booking";

Comment: Hi @Renjith i am running into same situation badly, could you please help me out on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17697899/how-to-map-dynamic-url-prj-noticeopen-2-in-spring-mvc-controller

Answer (score 2):

First consider how your dispatcher servlet is configured.  Currently it is mapped to the following url pattern:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/booking/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This means that only urls which contain the `booking` directory directly after the context root will be mapped.  So a url like `contextroot/AvailableBikes' will never get picked up and processed by the dispatcher.  I would recommend changing your url pattern to:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This mapping serves as almost a catch all mapping.  It will match all urls which are not mapped to another servlet.  Please note:  it will also create the need for you to setup configuration to map static resources such as css and js files.  This is explained in the Spring documentation.

Once you have made this change I think you should be able to hit the Controller with a URL like `rootcontext/AvailableBikes`.  Setup a debug point in the controller to confirm.  Also note that you will not use a url containing a direct path to the .jsp file but the path specified in the request mapping.  Your jsp file should be available @ `webcontent directory/WEB-INF/jsp/NumAvailableBikes.jsp`.

In order to display the `booking.jsp` which should be available @ `webcontent dir/WEB-INF/jsp/booking.jsp` the controller must be modified to return the `String` booking.

```
   @RequestMapping("/AvailableBikes")
    public String getAvailableBikes(Model model){
        // TOOD: Fix Date
        int availableBookings = bookingService.getAvailableBookings(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        model.addAttribute("NumAvailableBikes", Integer.toString(availableBookings));

        return "booking";
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how does Spring know, that if I visit `rootcontext/AvailableBikes`, that it should open the `booking.jps`? Edit: Ok this will hit my Controller (thank you so far for the debuggint tip).

Comment: It will know because the dispatcher servlet analyzes the url and the `@RequestMappings` that have been established.  It then chooses the appropriate controller method based upon if the value specified in the `@RequestMapping` matches the url.  Then in your controller method your returning a String and have a ViewResolver setup.  This takes the String and adds the prefix and suffix to the String to determine which JSP to render

Comment: return "NumAvailableBikes"; should be changed to return "booking";

Comment: @Renjith: Thank you so much! That's what I am looking for. Probably I was to blind to get this. Thank you like a million times!